# Is comma needed in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Below is a sentence from my book review. "China" is the name of the author.

Is it correct or incorrect to have a comma after the word *pay*?

> China finds a way to dissect both a woman's desire to find love and her penchant to make a man pay, if he plays around with that love.

Comment: You might find our sister site [ell.se] useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a comma. I always look if one needs an breathing space (sounds archaic but is almost always correct!). In this case it's more 'difficult' to read if you place a comma. According to the real grammatical rules, I don't think you need a comma either. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd say _this_ is easier (and especially for narrators who need to breathe): China finds a way to dissect both a woman's desire to find love, and her penchant to make a man pay if he plays around with that love. The comma I choose is not grammatically 'necessary' - some might even have a pet rule forbidding it - but punctuation is essentially here to help the reader / narrator, not make money for grammar-lawyers.